# Springboot - Httponly cookie Pass request to controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies

I Have cookies working in httponly on my frontend app.

I want to be able to refresh the page and still be logged in. I can do this, the cookie stays present. But the data from the login request where it provides the userProfile in the body wont be present.

I have the following class which filters requests:

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String email = jwtUtils.getEmailFromJwtToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) { return jwtUtils.getJwtFromCookies(request); }
}
```

But idealy i want to be handling the `whoAmI` from the auth controller.

```
 @GetMapping("/whoAmI")
    public ResponseEntity<?> whoAmI() {
...
...
...
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            if (cookies != null) {
                var temp = Arrays.stream(cookies)
                        .map(c -> c.getName() + "=" + c.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
            }
...
...
...

        return  ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
                .body(userService.findUserProfileUserByEmail(userDetails.getEmail()));
    }
```

It makes more sense for me to deal with this in controller instead of the filter. But how can I pass the request into the controller from the filter?

Comment: If I'm tracking, you can just accept the `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter in your controller's `whoAmI` method like: `public ResponseEntity<?> whoAmI(HttpServletRequest request)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a controller method with an argument of type `ServletRequest` and Spring will do the magic for you.

```
@GetMapping("/whoAmI")
public ResponseEntity<?> whoAmI(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
}
```

Take a look at [reference docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-methods) for possible handler method arguments.

Also spring-mvc is a thread-per-request model, so (if you don't use async spring-mvc features) you can get your servlet request anywhere in your code by using:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest();
```